# I want this code to have a couple of zero's between the actual counting and the year

Tags: php, wordpress

Can someone tell me how I can make the following script output:
2015000001 and then 201500002. Now it gives 20151 en 20152 etc. This script
counts my form submissions on contact form 7 on wordpress so each email
gets a unique incrementing number but I want the counting to start after 4 or
5 zeros. So 201500001

```
//Define the key to store in the database
define( 'CF7_COUNTER', 'cf7-counter' );

//Create the shortcode which will set the value for the DTX field
function cf7dtx_counter(){
$val = date( 'Y' ) . get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1; //Increment the current count
return $val;
}
add_shortcode('CF7_counter', 'cf7dtx_counter');

//Action performed when the mail is actually sent by CF7
function cf7dtx_increment_mail_counter(){
$val = get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1; //Increment the current count
update_option(CF7_COUNTER, $val); //Update the settings with the new count
}
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'cf7dtx_increment_mail_counter');
```

Thanks for the help so far. BTW does anyone know how I can reset
the number back to zero so it starts counting all over again.

I have it from this article so you can check:
http://sevenspark.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-counter-for-contact-form-7

Regards,
Amro

Comment: What does `get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0)` return?

Answer (score 1):

```
function cf7dtx_counter(){
    $year = date('Y');
    $counter = get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1;
    $val = sprintf('%d%05d', $year, $counter);
    return $val;
}
```

The second value (`$counter`) will be padded with `0` characters to a total length of 5 characters, that's what the `%05d` does.

Answer (score -1):

Sımply change this line

> $val = date( 'Y' ) . get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1; //Increment the current count

to;

> $val = date( 'Y' )*100000 + (get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1); //Increment the current count

to update the counter variable you have to call this function

> update_option(CF7_COUNTER, 0); //Update the settings with the new count

Comment: Thanks bro. Your amazing. So basically I should remove
update_option(CF7_COUNTER, 0); //Update the settings with the new count
after I received my first email right?

Comment: Nope. This will set the counter to zero.